# Setting JTable intercellspacing from synth xml

Tags: swing, jtable, synth

I have a synth XML that defines the property of the components that I use. Since I just now started with the synth XML need some guidance on setting the *intercell* spacing for the table I have.

I have defined the `<style>` tag and binded it with my component(`JTable`). I am able to change the background color and few other attributes. How can I set the inter-cell spacing of the table. I have gone through the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/synth/doc-files/componentProperties.html) to try it set using property. Which also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  Name:
                        {
                            title: 'Name',
                            width: '13%'
                        },
                    EmailAddress:
                        {
                            title: 'Email-Id',
                            width: '15%'   ......................> here u can specify width 
                        },
```

Comment: guess u misunderstood the question. it is swing JTable.

Comment: oops sorry. i thought it was jquery Jtable